# How can I avoid duplicate values when loading data using a spring batch job?

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-batch

I have a spring batch program that reads data from one database then processes the data then writes to an Oracle database. This batch program runs on a schedule once a day. How can I avoid adding the same record each time it runs and only new values from the source DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create unique index (or primary key, if possible (depending on whether you want to allow nulls or not)) which will cause Oracle to automatically reject all rows whose column(s) violate uniqueness.

Other options requires some programming.

**[EDIT: "silently" skip errors]**

This is what I meant:

```
for cur_r in (select col1, col2
              from another_table@db_link)
loop
  begin        --> you need inner BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END block
    insert into new_table (col1, col2)
      values (cur_r.col1, cur_r.col2);
  exception
    when dup_val_on_index then
      null;
  end;
end loop;
```

---

Another option uses pure SQL (i.e. no PL/SQL's *loop*):

```
insert into new_table (col1, col2)
  select col1, col2
  from another_table@db_link
  where (col1, col2) not in (select col1, col2 
                             from new_table);
```

This option doesn't even require unique index (which wouldn't harm, though) because `NOT IN` won't insert rows whose column values already exist in the target table.

Comment: Unfortunately the table does not have a unique value

Comment: How do you detect duplicates, then? Uniqueness doesn't have to be enforced on a single column. Combination of ALL COLUMNS can be unique. For example, based on Scott's DEPT table: `create unique index ui_dept on dept (deptno, dname, loc)`

Comment: Ahh okay. So I think every column together except for the audit columns would be considered unique. So I would create an index for those columns?

Comment: Right, make it **unique**. It takes a few moments to create it (if the table doesn't contain too many rows at the moment) and you'll be able to test it at once.

Comment: Okay so if a duplicate is about to be added is it just ignored? Or is an error thrown?

Comment: It depends on how you're inserting those rows. I don't know *spring*, but - all options are possible. If it were pure Oracle, if you don't do anything, you'll get an error. If you load it row-by-row (which is slow-by-slow), you can set exception handler to do *nothing* in the case of duplicates so you'd "silently" skip it (or even write such a row into the separate table). If it were Oracle's SQL*Loader, you'd have a really, really fast solution which allows you to decide how many errors you want to allow (set it to a large number to load the whole file); rejected rows are in the .BAD file.

Comment: How can I silently skip it?

Comment: I edited my message by adding some code; have a loo, please.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're concerned about not processing the same **source record** multiple times. If that's the case you can add a field on your *source table* indicating that the data has already been extracted.

Oh, and - put a unique primary key on your tables. All of them. Even the ones where you don't think you need it. The primary key you add today is the one where you WON'T say at a later date, "Damn. I wish that table had a primary key". [Don't ask me how I know...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhXV50r3FlY)

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using RepositoryItemReader as the source. If that is the case, you can add a custom method in the source Repository, including a validation condition to avoid already processed records, using @Query, and then go with that method in the RepositoryItemReader.

It would be something like

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM Records r WHERE r.isNew = 1")
Collection<Record> findAllNewRecords();
```

And then configure the reader like

```
RepositoryItemReader<Record> recordsReader = new RepositoryItemReader<>();
recordsReader.setRepository(recordsRepository);
recordsReader.setMethodName("findAllNewRecords");
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
create table T_UNIQUE_VALUE( a number,b number, c varchar2(100));

alter table T_UNIQUE_VALUE ADD CONSTRAINT C_UNIQUE_VALUE UNIQUE (a,b);
```

Define log error table. Oralce will create `err$_table_name`

```
BEGIN 
   DBMS_ERRLOG.create_error_log(dml_table_name => 'T_UNIQUE_VALUE'); 
END;
```

Test it.

```
execut 2 times  
insert into  T_UNIQUE_VALUE values(1,1,'a')  LOG ERRORS REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

--check table T_UNIQUE_VALUE and  err$_T_UNIQUE_VALUE
select * from err$_T_UNIQUE_VALUE; -- 1 row 
select * from T_UNIQUE_VALUE;  -- 1 row
```

Modify spring annotation.

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "insert into  T_UNIQUE_VALUE values(:a,:b,:c)  LOG ERRORS REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED",  nativeQuery = true)
void insert_balbla(...)
```